# How to implement "run once with retry" in Google Cloud Functions (with Firestore)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an asynchronous JavaScript function (returns a Promise) which can run on Google Cloud Functions. It takes a data object as a parameter. Once I create the data object I need the function to execute with it. When the function fails (Promise reject is called) the function must run again (1 hour) later with the same data object. Until it succeeds.

Example: The function is `sendEmail` and the data object contains the recipient, subject, and text. I want to send the email. But sometimes the mail server is down and `sendMail` fails. Then it must be tried later.

What is the correct way to implement this in a Firebase project using JavaScript Cloud Functions and Firestore?

I am looking for a recipe, not necessarily code.

I assume writing the data object as a document to Firestore is a good start. Then I could have an `onCreate` trigger to initiate the first attempt and an hourly schedule trigger for the next attempts. But how do I ensure, my function runs only once?

Comment: "But how do I ensure, my function runs only once?" You could set a flag in the Firestore document upon email sending success. However note that the two operations (email sending + flag writing) cannot be done in an atomic operations.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec This seams not enough. When timing is bad, `onCreate` could be triggered and start sending email. Then 10ms later the scheduled functions starts and sends the same email in parallel. Then both write the success flag. :-(

Comment: You should not use a [standard scheduled function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions?hl=en&authuser=0&gen=1st) (which would run every x minutes) but, better, schedule a Cloud Function to run exactly one hour after the failure, as explained in this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a).

Answer (score 1):

Scheduling a Cloud Function to run in the future with Cloud Tasks as explained in this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a) would do the trick.

In the **catch block** of your `onCreate` Cloud Function code you schedule another Cloud Function to run exactly one hour after the failure. This Cloud Function contains the same code than the `onCreate` Cloud Function (the only difference is how it is triggered and, BTW, you can write the code in an async JS function and call it from the two CFs).

There is however the rare possibility that the code in the catch block fails as well... To manage this case you can (a) set a flag in the Firestore document upon email sending success and, (b) have a [standard scheduled Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions?hl=en&authuser=0&gen=1st) that regularly checks if there are Firestore documents without this flag and which were created more than one (or more) hours ago.